# Blockquote background is oddly aligned in blog posts

Tags: bug, design, blog

Spacing on the blog looks a bit odd when quotations are used.  For example:

[image]

This looks like this in the WordPress editor:

[image]

The screen surround goes a bit too low, nearly colliding with the next paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed soon on the live server.